# Как проверить каким метдом авторизировался пользователь?

Tags: postgresql

Настраивая кровавый энтерпрайз узнал для себя, что последовательность типов авторизации влияет на поведение базы.

Если метод  `trusted` стоит после  `md5` то он отменяет вход без пароля.

> The first record with a matching connection type, client address,
>   requested database, and user name is used to perform authentication.
>   There is no "fall-through" or "backup": if one record is chosen and
>   the authentication fails, subsequent records are not considered. If no
>   record matches, access is denied.

Как можно проследить какой из способов авторизации был выбран?

**Ссылки**

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Код](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_12_STABLE/src/backend/libpq/auth.c#L344) обработки [hba](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_12_STABLE/src/backend/libpq/hba.c#L2071) как видно не экспортирует подходящих сведений в stats collector либо логи базы. Хотя в структуре HbaLine номер строки pg_hba файла хранится. Да, проверяется только первая совпадающая по типу соединения, имени пользователя, базы и адреса подключения строка. Поэтому проверять правила глазами.

Необходимые сведения доступны в `ClientAuthentication_hook` функции обратного вызова. Посмотрите на модуль [`auth_delay`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_12_STABLE/contrib/auth_delay/auth_delay.c) как крайне короткий пример написания расширения, при том именно для этой функции обратного вызова. (но да, это строго для компилируемых языков и в кровавом энтерпрайзе так развлекаться не позволят)

Либо можете написать письмо в [`pgsql-hackers`](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/) с аргументацией необходимости  и предложением куда-то эти сведения сохранять. Например, в лог при включенном `log_connections` вероятно будет вполне уместно, возможно в `errdetail` секции.